# Glimpse and partial views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, glimpse

I am trying to debug my routes in a MVC-4 application using glimpse.mvc

If I use only _layout.cshtml there is no problem, however if this calls other partial views, the loading of the page takes literally minutes and the browser (IE) remains unresponsive.

Is this a limitation of Glimpse?
Someone else noticed this behavior?

Thx

Comment: What version of Glimpse are you using? The newest version (RC1) should not have this behavior.

Comment: I installed it in VS 2012 from nuget with install-package glimpse.mvc3 and got V 0.87

How could I nuget RC1 ?

Comment: Just `install-package glimpse.mvc -pre`.

Comment: Note: [Glimpse.Mvc4](https://nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.Mvc4/) is now out and does not have this issue.

Comment: Well, I'm running Glimpse.Mvc4 1.5.2 now and I see the same problem. When I'm rendering a partial view the page doesn't finish loading. If I run the exact same Razor code right in the page, it runs fine. :(